# what happen if do not put text files in string.xml in android?

Tags: android, string, text, textview

i did not put some text in string.xml and there is a yellow alert symbol in side of Textview field. i want to know does it have problem and what happen, if do not put texts in **string.xml** in android?

Comment: strings.xml enables string's localization. If you hardcode your strings inside the layout file you will not have localization

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it will not cause a problem in the short term, it is not good practice and will cause you issues in the future if you decide to support multiple languages.

Answer (score 1):

Well, setting your text directly on your layout file can be a source of future problems and its not recommended.

Consider this scenario: You use the same string "Foo" in many layout files and then you decided to change to "Bar". If you have hardcoded that, you will need to make changes in all layout files and there might be a chance to leave some inconsistent text. But if you place it in the `strings.xml` file, you will have only to change in one place.

Also, if you want to add translations to your app, the Android system can handle it automatically for you if you use the `strings.xml`.

You might want to take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will happen.

string.xml used to:

1. localization
   res/values-fr/strings.xml
   res/values-ja/strings.xml
2. ease of editing and to save memory when reusing.

I Recommend you to put text files in string.xml